# How to use 'readonly' function in Select Box?

Tags: jsp, drop-down-menu

I have a select box that selects a certain data from DB.

And if am to give no other option to the Select Box but the one it is selected, how should I edit the code? Knowing that 'readonly' doesn't work in Select box.

**Following is the code.**

```
   <select name="courses" id="courses">
        <c:forEach var="A" items="${exam}" >
            <option value="${A.cd}"><c:out value="${A.person}" /></option>
        </c:forEach>
    </select>
```

Comment: which option you have to make readonly ????

Comment: <option value="${A.cd}"><c:out value="${A.person}" /></option>
is a default and should be selected as 'readonly'

Comment: it is in loop if you will make it readonly all option will become readonly

Comment: that's what I want actually. Could you please help me out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try something like this

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab" disabled>Saab</option>
  <option value="vw" disabled>VW</option>
  <option value="audi"disabled >Audi</option>
</select>
```